# flutter injectable resolve dependencies from packages

Tags: flutter, injectable

I have a class which has an instance of [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) as dependency. how can i solve it using injectable?

Answer (score 0):

I use `get_it` as my dependency injection.

https://pub.dev/packages/get_it

Example `main.dart`:

```
// declare a global variable
GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;
```

Your dependency injection file:

```
import 'package:YOUR_PACKAGE/main.dart' as main;
main.getIt.registerSingleton<Dio>(Dio());
```

Then, when you want to use it:

```
import 'package:YOUR_PACKAGE/main.dart' as main;
Dio dio => main.getIt<Dio>();
```